# How to use Vich uploader with easyAdmin 3 on Symfony 5

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5, easyadmin, vichuploaderbundle

I've been trying to use VichUploader to upload files on a Symfony project, already using EasyAdmin 3.

I've configured everything correctly, but I'm getting this error:

> The "pieceJointeFile" image field must define the directory where the
> images are uploaded using the setUploadDir() method.

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\InventaireRepository;
use DateTime;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;

My entity

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=InventaireRepository::class)
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 */
class Inventaire
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Conducteur::class, inversedBy="inventaires")
     */
    private $conducteur;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date")
     */
    private $dateInventaire;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $pieceJointe;

    /**
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="pieceJointe", fileNameProperty="pieceJointe")
     */
    private $pieceJointeFile;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $updatedAt;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->updatedAt = new DateTime();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getConducteur(): ?Conducteur
    {
        return $this->conducteur;
    }

    public function setConducteur(?Conducteur $conducteur): self
    {
        $this->conducteur = $conducteur;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDateInventaire(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->dateInventaire;
    }

    public function setDateInventaire(\DateTimeInterface $dateInventaire): self
    {
        $this->dateInventaire = $dateInventaire;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPieceJointeFile() {
        return $this->pieceJointeFile;
    }

    public function setPieceJointeFile($pieceJointeFile): void
    {
        $this->pieceJointeFile = $pieceJointeFile;

        if($pieceJointeFile) {
            $this->updatedAt = new DateTime();
        }
    }

    public function getPieceJointe() {
        return $this->pieceJointe;
    }


    public function setPieceJointe($pieceJointe):self
    {
        $this->pieceJointe = $pieceJointe;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getUpdatedAt()
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }
}
```

vich uploader configuration

```
vich_uploader:
    db_driver: orm

    mappings:
        pieceJointe:
            uri_prefix: /files/pieceJointe
            upload_destination: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/files/pieceJointe'
```

and finally My crud controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Admin;

use App\Entity\Inventaire;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Config\Action;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Config\Actions;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Config\Crud;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\AbstractCrudController;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\AssociationField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\DateField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\ImageField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\TextField;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Form\Type\VichFileType;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Form\Type\VichImageType;

class InventaireCrudController extends AbstractCrudController
{
    public static function getEntityFqcn(): string
    {
        return Inventaire::class;
    }


    public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
    {
        return [
            DateField::new('dateInventaire'),
            AssociationField::new('conducteur'),
            TextField::new('pieceJointeFile')->setFormType(VichFileType::class, [
                'delete_label' => 'supprimer?'
            ])->onlyOnForms(),
            ImageField::new('pieceJointe')->setBasePath('/files/pieceJointe')->onlyOnDetail(),
            ImageField::new('pieceJointeFile')->setFormType(VichImageType::class)
        ];
    }



    public function configureActions(Actions $actions): Actions
    {
        return $actions
            ->add(Crud::PAGE_INDEX, Action::DETAIL);
    }
}
```

Finally, I want to clarify that when using `TextField` it works correctly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can solve this problem by creating a simple field class

```
<?PHP

namespace App\Field;

use App\Form\MetaDataType;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Contracts\Field\FieldInterface;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\FieldTrait;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Form\Type\VichImageType;

final class VichImageField implements FieldInterface
{
    use FieldTrait;

    public static function new(string $propertyName, ?string $label = 'Image'): self
    {
        return (new self())
            ->setProperty($propertyName)
            ->setLabel($label)
            // this template is used in 'index' and 'detail' pages
            ->setTemplatePath('admin/field/vich_image.html.twig')
            // this is used in 'edit' and 'new' pages to edit the field contents
            // you can use your own form types too
            ->setFormType(VichImageType::class)
            ->addCssClass('field-vich-image')
        ;
    }
}
```

And then use it in your crud controllers

```
use App\Field\VichImageField;

...
yield VichImageField::new('image')->hideOnForm();
yield VichImageField::new('imageFile')->onlyOnForms();
```

Two times here because you need `image` field to render and `imageFile` on forms

```
{# admin/field/vich_image.html.twig #}
{% if field.value %}
  {% if field.value|match('/\.svg$/') %}
    <div class="thumbnail">
      {{ vich_uploader_asset(entity.instance, field.property ~ 'File', entity.fqcn) }}
    </div>
  {% else %}
    {% set html_id = 'ea-lightbox-' ~ field.uniqueId %}
    <a href="#" class="ea-lightbox-thumbnail" data-featherlight="#{{ html_id }}" data-featherlight-close-on-click="anywhere">
        <img src="{{ vich_uploader_asset(entity.instance, field.property ~ 'File', entity.fqcn)|imagine_filter('admin_thumbnail') }}" alt="{{ entity.name }}" class="img-fluid">
    </a>

    <div id="{{ html_id }}" class="ea-lightbox">
        <img src="{{ vich_uploader_asset(entity.instance, field.property ~ 'File', entity.fqcn)|imagine_filter('admin_full') }}" alt="{{ entity.name }}">
    </div>
  {% endif %}
{% else %}
    <span class="badge badge-secondary">
        Empty
    </span>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Hi, can you share the sourcecode of your 'vich_image.html.twig'?

Comment: Hi @Johnny, I've added it to my answer

Comment: Thank you. Can you maybe also share your 2 imagine filters admin_thumbnail and admin_full?

Comment: In general, you don't need those filters at all. But if you want they are done via liip/LiipImagineBundle via config, mine looks like this:

```
liip_imagine:
    driver: "gd"
    filter_sets:
        admin_thumbnail: {quality: 75, filters: {thumbnail: {size: [120, 90], mode: outbound}}}
        admin_full: {quality: 90}
```

See documentation here  https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/LiipImagineBundle/basic-usage.html

Comment: Thanks, I thought maybe the filters are the reason it wasn't working for me. But they weren't. I am trying to implement that but for a collection of VichImages. The lightbox feature in the twig file does not work, because the image comes from a collection. I just left that out and now it works. In the form though I am still looking for a solution: `$imagesForm = CollectionField::new('images')->setEntryType(VichImageType::class);` does not work. It tells me `The class "Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection" is not uploadable.`. Have you ever implemented a collection of VichImages with EasyAdmin 3?

Comment: I probably should mention, that I have a Device and a DeviceImage entity (oneToMany). And the Device entity has an 'images' property which is a collection that contains multiple DeviceImage entities.

Comment: @Johnny For collection of images it is even easier: just make form for your DeviceImage entity with VichImage field like so `$builder->add('imageFile', VichImageType::class)', and use it in your collection field 'CollectionField::new('images')
                ->setEntryType(DeviceImageType::class)
                ->allowAdd()
                ->setFormTypeOptions([
                    'by_reference' => false,
                    ]);'

Comment: Edit: Why can I not adress this directly to you with the @ tag? @Flash 
Thanks a lot, mate! It works now :) This whole symfony and easyadmin struggle keeps giving me headaches for the last few weeks.

Comment: Hi!, Where was the VichImageField field class created?.. src/Form/.. ?
Thnz!

Comment: @Candelo yes you can create it in `src/Form`

Comment: Just added this to an EasyAdmin 4 project. Works nicely! However, for the lightbox to work you need to add the following to the `VichImageField`: `->addJsFiles(Asset::fromEasyAdminAssetPackage('field-image.js'))` (`Asset` is imported from `EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Config\Asset`).

Answer (score 13):

```
$imageFile = TextareaField::new('imageFile')->setFormType(VichImageType::class);
```

Put **TextareaField** to remplace the **ImageField** and it's works for me!!!!!

$imageFile = TextareaField

$image = ImageField

Answer (score 4):

I found that documentation for EasyAdmin and VichUploaderBundle contains a mistake
which follow to next exception:
The "imageFile" image field must define the directory where the images are uploaded using the setUploadDir() method.

solution is simple:

```
//Entity
/**
  *
  * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="video_image", fileNameProperty="imageName")
  *
  * @var File|null
*/
    private $imageFile;
//......

/**
  * @param File|null $imageFile
  * @return $this
*/
public function setImageFile(File $imageFile = null): self
{
    $this->imageFile = $imageFile;
    if (null !== $imageFile) {
        $this->updatedAt = new DateTime();
    }
  return $this;
}
```

```
//Admin Crud controller
// any type of field isnt correct except one
$coverImage = ImageField::new('imageFile')->setFormType(VichImageType::class); 

//this is a proper way of how to
$coverImage = Field::new('imageFile')->setFormType(VichImageType::class);
```

not required to create any custom field type or anything else except proper configuration in `vich_uploader.yaml`

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue.
I solved it by reverting to the version "easycorp/easyadmin-bundle": "3.1.6"

Good luck!

Comment: Downgrading isn't a good solution nor a secure solution especially with a bundle uploading (potentially unsecure) files.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. I solved it by changing in Controller this :
`use App\Field\VichImageField;`

```
...
yield VichImageField::new('image')->hideOnForm();
yield VichImageField::new('imageFile')->onlyOnForms();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your CrudController

```
    public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
    {
        $name = TextField::new('name');
        $description = TextField::new('description');
        $image = ImageField::new('image')
            ->setTemplatePath('admin/fields/vich_image.html.twig')
            ;
        $imageFile = Field::new('imageFile')
            ->setFormType(VichImageType::class)
            ;

        if (Crud::PAGE_INDEX === $pageName) {
            return [$name, $description, $image];
        } elseif (Crud::PAGE_DETAIL === $pageName) {
            return [$image];
        } elseif (Crud::PAGE_NEW === $pageName) {
            return [$name, $description, $imageFile];
        } elseif (Crud::PAGE_EDIT === $pageName) {
            return [$name, $description, $imageFile];
        }
    }
```

And here is slightly updated `admin/fields/vich_image.html.twig` version, which go fullscreen for smaller screen:

```
{% if field.value %}
    <a href="#" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#imageModal{{ field.uniqueId }}">
        <img src="{{ vich_uploader_asset(entity.instance, 'imageFile')|imagine_filter('thumb') }}">
    </a>
    <div class="modal fade" id="imageModal{{ field.uniqueId }}" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal for {{ entity.instance.name }}" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-fullscreen-lg-down">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">{{ entity.instance.name }}
                    </h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <img src="{{ vich_uploader_asset(entity.instance, 'imageFile')|imagine_filter('creative_dim_down') }}">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

For reference, here are the used liip filter for the thumbnail and the dim scaling of the image

```
liip_imagine:

    # [...]

    filter_sets:
        cache: ~

        thumb:
            quality: 75
            filters:
                thumbnail: { size: [120, 90], mode: outbound }
                background: { size: [124, 94], position: center, color: '#000000' }

        creative_dim_down:
            quality: 90
            filters:
                scale:  
                    dim: [ 800, 1000 ]
```